# Change the Dropdownlist selected values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am populating a DDL with another DDL and i am getting the value from another page

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DropDownList1.DataSource = ProfileMasterDAL.bindcountry();
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "--Select country--");

        }


        if(Session["uname"]!=null)
        {
              DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Session["country"].ToString();
           ProfileMasterBLL bll=new ProfileMasterBLL();
            foreach (var VARIABLE in ProfileMasterDAL.bindcountry())
            {
                if (VARIABLE.ToString().Contains(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text))
                {
                    var query = (ProfileMasterDAL.GetStatesByCountrys(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text));
                    DropDownList2.DataSource = query;
                    DropDownList2.DataBind();
                 }
            }


            TextBox8.Text = Session["email"].ToString();
            string pwd = Session["pwd"].ToString();
            TextBox9.Attributes.Add("value",pwd);
            TextBox10.Attributes.Add("value", pwd);

        }
    }
```

but the problem is whenever i change the DDL value is fixed to the session value as it is in page_load so how can i change the value to selected item in the DDL.

Comment: You might want to say "drop down list" rather than "DDL". It's clear after reading your question what you mean, but my initial reaction to your question *title* was that you're asking about data definition language.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`OnSelectedIndexChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.onselectedindexchanged.aspx) along with setting the [`AutoPostBack` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback.aspx) to true for the drop down list.

And in the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event handler, add the code to populate the second drop down list.

Comment: Already i have done that but the dropdownlist.selected value is assigned to a session value in pageload, so even though i am selecting some other country the session value is remaining.

Answer (score 0):

If have understood the question correct, you wanted to change the value of DropDownList2
depending upon the value of DropDownList1, intial value of dropdownlist comes from another page

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DropDownList1.DataSource = ProfileMasterDAL.bindcountry();
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "--Select country--");

            //get the selected country from another page
            string selectedCountry = Convert.ToString(Session["country"]);

            //set the selected value
            DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(selectedCountry).Selected = true;

            //Bind Dropdonwlist2
             BindDropDownList(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);

        }

        /*
         remaining code
         */
    }
```

Bind the dropdonwList 2 code

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Bind dropdownlist2 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="selectedCountry"></param>
    protected void BindDropDownList(string selectedCountry)
    {
        ProfileMasterBLL bll = new ProfileMasterBLL();
        foreach (var VARIABLE in ProfileMasterDAL.bindcountry())
        {
            if (VARIABLE.ToString().Contains(selectedCountry))
            {
                var query = (ProfileMasterDAL.GetStatesByCountrys(selectedCountry));
                DropDownList2.DataSource = query;
                DropDownList2.DataBind();
            }
        }

    }
```

On Selected Index change of dropdonwlist1, now the value will change

set autopostback true for dropdownlist1

```
DropDownList1.AutoPostBack = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// DropDownList1 Selcted Index change
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected  void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         BindDropDownList(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
    }
```

Hope this will solve ur problem

Comment: When i do this i am getting an error like 
Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList.

Comment: The problem is the value from the session is not getting changed even though i select a new value in ddl

Comment: @Chandra sekhar 
1. if you are facing exception “Cannot have multiple items selected”, first clear selection of dropdown
   DropDownList1.ClearSelection();
before setting any new value programmatically 
2. if u want to change the value of seesion than you have to do in event DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged 
Session["country"] = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DropDownList1.DataSource = ProfileMasterDAL.bindcountry();
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "--Select country--");

            if(Session["uname"]!=null)
            {
                DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Session["country"].ToString();
                BindList()
            }

        }
        if(Session["uname"]!=null)
        {
            TextBox8.Text = Session["email"].ToString();
            string pwd = Session["pwd"].ToString();
            TextBox9.Attributes.Add("value",pwd);
            TextBox10.Attributes.Add("value", pwd);     
        }
     }
```

add method for bind ddl2

```
private void BindList()
{
    ProfileMasterBLL bll=new ProfileMasterBLL();
    foreach (var VARIABLE in ProfileMasterDAL.bindcountry())
    {
      if (VARIABLE.ToString().Contains(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text))
      {
         var query = 
       ProfileMasterDAL.GetStatesByCountrys(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text));
                    DropDownList2.DataSource = query;
                    DropDownList2.DataBind();
      }
}
```

set autopostback true for dropdownlist1 and add selectedIndexChanged

```
protected  void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         BindList();
    }
```